# above vs over to talk about amount of money

Tags: grammar, word-choice

They spent £160,000 or **above** on toys, CDs, and perfume.
They spent £160,000 or **over** on toys, CDs, and perfume.
Which one of these sentences is correct?

Comment: Why do you think one is incorrect?

Comment: I have seen sentences with both, but according to Cambridge grammar "We normally use over not above with numbers". This confuses me. Here is the link: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/above-or-over

Comment: Why would you not simply use _more_?

Comment: Yeah it is the most common choice, but I wanted to see if I could use above or over as well

Comment: _Over £160,000_ would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Both are idiomatic in the US, though "over" is probably more common.  "Above" would tend to be used when the intent was to emphasize "levels", metaphorically like rising water.

Comment: I will note that, in the US, stock market "levels" are expressed in dollars (generally using an average of multiple stock prices).   And the terms "above" and "below" are often use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Licensing references for the usages *are* quite hard to find.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/above) gives under **above**:

> • (adverb) 1 [the part of speech is disputed by others]
>
> - 1.1 Higher in grade or rank.
>
> *an officer of the rank of superintendent or above*

(this sense, for grades / ranks, is not available with 'over')

> - 1.2 Higher than a specified amount, rate, or norm.
>
> *boats of 31 ft. or above*

And, under **over**, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/over) gives:

> (adverb) ...
>
> - more; in excess; beyond
>
> *three hours or over*

So with numbers, or especially, as here, with measures (numbers + units), either is acceptable. Cambridge Dictionary ... Grammar is saying that with pure numbers and numbers with standard units or non-physical 'units' like *people*, *cars*, *outside the 'or over/above usage*, , 'over' is the more usual choice . 'There were over 50 000 deaths from the virus.' But the examples it scores through (*I get above sixty emails a day.* / *If you weigh above 100 kilograms, then you may need to start a diet.*) are just less usual (and more formal in register), by no means unacceptable.

And as @Isabel points out, *more* (and where necessary *more than*) may be the most idiomatic choice. 'They spent £160,000 or more on toys, CDs, and perfume.'